# checksum validation fro rsa encryption in openssl?

Tags: openssl, rsa

Does rsa encryption method in OpenSSL provide some sort of checksum validation ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think your question might be better posted in crypto.stackexchange.com.

That said, the answer is...  sorta.  OpenSSL is PKCS#1 compliant and PKCS#1 padding doesn't utilize a checksum, persay, but the checksum does need to conform to certain criteria, which I'd say has the effect of a simple parity-bit style checksum.

OAEP padding actually uses cryptographic hashes within it that provide for more elaborate validation.